# requestFiltering not working for device name urls

Tags: asp.net, web-config, iis-8, requestfiltering

Hi I am new to IIS and Asp Net programming. I am working with IIs 8.0 and I am wondering why the requestFiltering method for denyUrlSequences is not working for ms-dos device names like /AUX.

Here is my code in the Web.config

```
  <system.webServer>
      <security>
        <requestFiltering>
          <!-- block /CFIDE -->
          <denyUrlSequences>
              <add sequence="/AUX"/>
          </denyUrlSequences>
        </requestFiltering>
      </security>
  </system.webServer>
```

this works if the  but it does not work for the case with AUX. It just gives server errors not Http 404.5. Is there any other configurations I must do to get this to work?

THank you!

Comment: Your sequence in config has an extra slash so why do you think it works for cases without the slash?

Comment: Still does not work with <add sequence="AUX"/> or <add sequence="/AUX"/> :(

Comment: @James - did you resolve this issue?